# Launch bar problem

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

Pls see the attached image, seem to me that I press a key combination that put numbers in my launch bar and not allow it to hide. How can I restore my default launch bar behavior and remove those numbers and letters ('s' and 't')?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its sounds like sticky keys got turned on.  Follow these steps to turn it off.

To check open 'System Settings'
[image]
Then open 'Universal Access'
[image]
Switch to the 'Typing' tab and turn 'Sticky Keys' off (if its on)
[image]

Hopefully this will fix your problem.

***NOTE:***
You might have to press several keys, like  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  and  <kbd>Super</kbd>  after you turn sticky keys off.

Comment: I did something, not know what, and all go to the normality ;) Seem to me that I open and maximized an application. Still, what is it all about sticky keys?

Comment: Sticky keys makes a function key act like you are pressing it unil you press it again.  If you turned this on (maybe by accident) it will show the numbers until you press 'Super' or open the dash.  Try pressing 'Super' and let me know if the numbers appear again.

Comment: Thanks @iSeth. I have sticky key off, so how I get there? and more important, how can I out from that state? cos I really don't know how I out to from that odd launch bar, I this is not the first time this happen to me :(

Comment: Have you restarted the computer latly?

Comment: Yes. But the problem go away without restart the laptop. I think that was a combination of keys that I press or something like that, but I really can't figure out what keys each time this happen to me I pressed. That thing happen to me about one time per month or something.